# Java Pattern for regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a 2 column tsv file with column one having

```
1-FN3Z1-206329557431
1-FN411-153115736976
```

Where I am trying to remove the first two parts of the value (i.e to extract `206329557431` and `153115736976`). I've used online regex tool to generate the patterns

pattern

`".*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+)"`   AND      `".*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+)"`

Independently they work fine. I'm trying to look for a combined regex pattern. Any pointers as to how this can be done.

Comment: Do you just want everything after the second hyphen? Do you just want to skip the first 8 characters? What precisely defines the part you want to capture?

Comment: `String str = "1-FN3Z1-206329557431"; str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't use `split` for example :

```
String spl = "1-FN411-153115736976".split("-")[2];
```

If you want a regex you can use `(.*?-){2}(.*)`, which mean get everything after the second `-`

## regex demo

**Output**

```
206329557431
153115736976
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings in your TSV file all have the same widths and patterns, then you can just use substring here:

```
String tsv = "1-FN3Z1-206329557431";
System.out.println(tsv.substring(8));
```

## Demo

Comment: W'll, if I have to put it in a regex rule, how would be do that. The one which you proposed, for sure works. I'm just trying to understand how to write regex patterns

Comment: @Betafish Update your question and tell us the rules for what the TSV strings might look like.  Then an exact pattern could be written.  If they are all really fixed width, then I recommend just using substring here; you don't need regex.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regexp : `.-.{5}-` looks like it can matches all statements but it depends on your format.[image: Example of pattern work]

Here is Java code example :

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String test = "1-FN3Z1-206329557431    1-FN411-153115736976";

    String result = test.replaceAll(".-.{5}-", "");

    assertEquals("206329557431    153115736976", result);
}
```